# Difference between constraintRight_toRightOf and constraintRight_toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

What is the actual difference between the difference between the below lines

```
constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you constrain the view to the layout, the second one doesn't really make sence. If you use it, the view will fall out of the layouts bounds.

If you constrain a view to another view, then the first one will align the right side of the view to the right side of the other view. The second one will align the right side of the view to the left side of the other view.

Look at the picture:
Button A is constrained to the Button at the top with

```
constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/otherButton"
```

Button B is constrained with

```
constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/otherButton"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret those properties as "The current view right side will be placed to the X view Right/Left side"

So in your particular case

```
constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Will be interpreted as "The current view right side will be place to the parent view right side". Basically meaning the the view will be constrained to be right to the right side of the parent.

and

```
constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Will be interpreted as "The current view right side will be place to the parent view left side". Basically meaning the the view will be constrained to be right to the left side of the parent. (Which is out of the layout when the value is parent)

Answer (score 0):

In constraint layout Screen is considered as parent for the underlying views.

If you write

`constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` means:

Place the right side of current View to Screen's right side

`constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"` means:

Place the right side of current View to the left side of Screen. This could potentially lead to layout out of bounds.

Following diagram depicts how the attributes are placed for the view:
[image: Constraint view attributes]

More details with complete explanation of these attributes is available [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/constraints-layout-best-layout-ever-230175272c0f).